# Erro na sintaxe em query no PrepareStatement

Tags: java, mysql

Estou recebendo essa mensagem de erro e não consigo achar o porque:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '?,?,?)' at line 1

o código que retorna o erro é esse:

```
    public void adicionar() {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO genius.produtos_comissao_extra (Id_produto, Data_abertura, Valor) VALUES (?,?,?)";

        if (!txtValor.getText().equals("")) {

            try {
                pst = conexao.prepareStatement(sql);
                // passando o conteúdo dos calendarios para o "?"
                pst.setString(1, lblId.getText());
                Date data = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()); // data atual
                String d = data.toString();
                pst.setString(2, d);
                pst.setString(3, txtValor.getText());
                pst.execute(sql);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Comissão extra inserida no produto");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }  

        } else { 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Informe o valor");

        }
    }
```

O schema da tabela é esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se os 3 campos da sua tabela do insert não forem string, vai dar erro mesmo. Tem certeza de que `Id_produto` e `Data_abertura` são strings e não, respectivamente, int e datetime?

Comment: eles eram sim int e datetime, mas mesmo alterando os dois para varchar o problema continuou, tentei também usar pst.setInt e pst.setDate e o problema continuou

Comment: Então algum campo está com nome errado, ou o caminho da sua tabela.

Comment: eu testei primeiro no MySql e funcionou com o código: INSERT INTO genius.produtos_comissao_extra (Id_produto, Data_abertura, Valor) VALUES (2,'2016-09-06',5.3); eu não consegui achar a diferença

Comment: Adicione o esquema da sua tabela(nome, campos e seus tipos) na pergunta.

Comment: esta ai diegofm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente o seguinte:

```
public void adicionar() {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO genius.produtos_comissao_extra (Id_produto, Data_abertura, Valor) VALUES (?,?,?)";

    if (!txtValor.getText().equals("")) {

        try {
            pst = conexao.prepareStatement(sql);
            // passando o conteúdo dos calendarios para o "?"
            pst.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(lblId.getText()));
            java.sql.Date data = new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis()); // data atual
            pst.setDate(2, data);
            pst.setString(3, txtValor.getText());
            pst.executeUpdate();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Comissão extra inserida no produto");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }  

    } else { 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Informe o valor");

    }
}
```

O problema é que `Id_produto` espera um inteiro, e `Data_abertura` espera um `Date`, e você está passando tudo como string. O que fiz nesse código foi converter o `lblId.getText()` para `int` e pegar a data corrente no formato em que o `PrepareStatement` espera(o banco espera um tipo [sql.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) e não um [util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)). E como se trata de um *insert*, você pode chamar `pst.executeUpdate();`, caso não necessite de nenhum retorno.

> Obs.: Atente-se ao fato de que o campo *lblId.getText()* precisa ter um valor que possa ser convertido para inteiro, qualquer valor diferente disso(ex.: string em branco, null ou digito misturado com caracter) vai estourar um `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: cara, deu certinho, muito obrigado...